# Initialising Variables in java

Tags: java, variables, initialization

How would I initialise the string `name` and the instance variable named `right` in the superclass to `true` from the `HighRights` class?

So if `high` is an instance of `HighRights` then

```
high.getSecret();
```

should return `the secret is 42`

```
public class SecurityRights {
  private boolean right;
  private boolean canreadSecret;
  String SECRET="the secret is 42";

  public SecurityRights(boolean r) {
    right =r;
    if (r) canreadSecret=true; else canreadSecret=false;
  }

  boolean getRight(){
    return right;
  }

  boolean canReadSecret(){
    return canreadSecret;
  }

  String getSecret(){
    if (canreadSecret) return SECRET; else return "access denied";
  }
}

public class HighRights extends SecurityRights
{
  private String name;

  public HighRights(String n){

  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    HighRights s= new HighRights("Lisa");
    System.out.print(s.getName() +" "+s.getSecret());                
  }
}
```

Comment: The example doesn't compile. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You call the Parent's constructor by calling `super()`.

So in your case

```
super(booleanValue);
```

Usually, this would be placed in the first line of your child constructor.

---

You could also change the privacy level from `private` to `protected`, and then you would be able to access it in all child objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a method just like you did when calling getSecret() and intialize and boolean and string.
OR
you can use the super methods. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) is some more info. You would pretty much be making a constructor for the class, but since an instance of the class is never really created only a Child of that instance, you need to use the super command to make constructors.

Answer (score 0):

The inherited class would have the following implementation:-

```
class HighRights extends SecurityRights
{
  private String name;

  public HighRights(boolean r,String n){
    super(r);
    this.name = n;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    HighRights s= new HighRights(false,"Lisa");
    System.out.print(s.getName() +" "+s.getSecret());                
  }
}
```

In this implementation, the `super` keyword is used. `super` keyword is used when you need to call the `superclass's` constructor from the constructor of the `subclass`. Since you needed to access the `right` variable of `SecurityRights` from the constructor of `HighRights`, you could access it by using the `super` keyword. More information can be found at oracle's [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Also, you gave an argument in the constructor of `SecurityRights` but you didn't assign it to any variable. Please avoid these mistakes.